# Update with self-join

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, ora-00933

I want to update a table to indicate that some rows are parents of others, so I added a "parentid" column to the table.  The following query finds all the parents:

```
SELECT ca1.id, ca2.id 
FROM contactassociations ca1
JOIN contactassociations ca2 ON (ca1.contactid = ca2.contactid)
where ca1.entitytable = 'EMPLOYER' AND
ca2.entitytable = 'CLIENT';
```

but when I try to adapt that syntax to do the update, it doesn't work:

```
UPDATE contactassociations ca1
SET    ca1.parentid = ca2.id
JOIN  contactassociations ca2 ON (ca1.contactid = ca2.contactid)
WHERE ca1.entitytable = 'EMPLOYER' AND ca2.entitytable = 'CLIENT';
```

I get:

```
Error starting at line 6 in command:
UPDATE contactassociations ca1
SET    ca1.parentid = ca2.id
JOIN  contactassociations ca2 ON (ca1.contactid = ca2.contactid)
WHERE ca1.entitytable = 'EMPLOYER' AND ca2.entitytable = 'CLIENT'
Error at Command Line:7 Column:28
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Note that line 7 column 28 is the end of the "SET" line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oracle does not support `JOIN` clause in `UPDATE` statements.

Use this:

```
MERGE
INTO    contactassociations ca1
USING   contactassociations ca2
ON      (
        ca1.contactid = ca2.contactid
        AND ca1.entitytable = 'EMPLOYER'
        AND  ca2.entitytable = 'CLIENT'
        )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     parentid = ca2.id
```

Comment: I've never heard of "MERGE" before.  Thanks.

Comment: @Paul: it's `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` in one statement. `SQL Server` supports it too (since `2008`)

Comment: You can update a select statement including joins provided the table being updated is key-preserved.

Comment: @Adam: that's what I was going to say as well, but then I saw the MERGE statement which does the job nicely :)

Answer (score 8):

I find the following style simpler to read, but you need to use an alias after the UPDATE key word, not the table name:

```
UPDATE ca1
SET    ca1.parentid = ca2.id
FROM contactassociations ca1
LEFT JOIN contactassociations ca2 ON (ca1.contactid = ca2.contactid)
WHERE ca1.entitytable = 'EMPLOYER' AND ca2.entitytable = 'CLIENT'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Method #1
update emp set MANAGERNAME= mgr.EMPNAME
FROM SelfJoinTable emp , SelfJoinTable mgr where emp.MANAGERID = mgr.EMPID

-- Method #2
update emp 
set  MANAGERNAME= mgr.EMPNAME  
FROM SelfJoinTable emp 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN SelfJoinTable mgr 
   ON emp.MANAGERID = mgr.EMPID

-- Method #3
update emp 
set  MANAGERNAME= mgr.EMPNAME  
FROM SelfJoinTable emp 
   JOIN SelfJoinTable mgr 
   ON emp.MANAGERID = mgr.EMPID

-- Method #4
update emp 
set  MANAGERNAME= mgr.EMPNAME 
 FROM SelfJoinTable emp 
   inner JOIN SelfJoinTable mgr 
   ON emp.MANAGERID = mgr.EMPID
```